# How do the components of a cross product transform?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, transformation, tensors

Let $x^{j}$ and $y^{k}$ be the components of two vectors $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$. According to the way the compontents of $x$ and $y$ transform when we change the basis, we know they are $(1,0)$-tensors.
But how do the components of the cross product $x\times y$ transform when we change the basis? I know that they are given by $c_{i}:=\epsilon_{ijk}x^{j}y^{k}$ (Edit: I forgot to say that I used the Einstein notation here).
This object has an index below, so I ask myself if it is a $(0,1)$-tensor. But I'm pretty sure thats not true. 
So can someone tell me what object this is and how its components transform when we change the basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're correct, in some sense, the cross-product of two vectors is not really a vector of the same *type*. The language used to distinguish the two types is:

1. **polar vectors**: flip sign of component under coordinate inversion
2. **axial vectors**: do not flip sign of component under inversion (also known as pseudovector see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector))

All of this is in three dimensions. That is key, because what really underlies this is the correspondence between one and two forms in three dimension. Hodge duality allows us to exchange:
$$ adx+bdy+cdz \leftrightarrows a dy \wedge dz + a dz \wedge dx+ a dx \wedge dy$$
Of course, these are not tensors of the same type. We have type $(1,0)$ vs type $(2,0)$. Again, Hodge duality allows us to identify these. So, incidentally, there are also identifications of $p$ and $n-p$ forms in higher dimensions which generalize this willful obfuscation of polar and axial vectors.

Of course, exchanging $a\partial_x+b\partial_y+c\partial_z$ for $adx+bdy+cdz$ is also exploiting another isomorphism. In Euclidean space it doesn't seem like much, but, beware in physics when the Minkowski metric lurks about, there are pesky minus signs which appear from "raising" or "lowering" the indices. All of this is nicely captured by the so-called **musical isomorphisms** which use $\sharp$ or $\flat$ to denote the raising or lowering operation in a coordinate free fashion. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) or [this useful MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60945/36530)

Comment: I never understood the whole point about "pseudovectors" and "axial vectors". If I apply a reflection on the result of a cross product, it will behave normally. If I apply a reflection to the factors in the cross product, the result will change a sign, which is totally normal, since reflections are not algebra homomorphisms on the $\mathbb{R}^3$ Lie-algebra. The automorphism group of said Lie-algebra is the group of orientation-preserving isometries, which reflections are not.

Comment: @Uldreth well, I guess the point is that inversions do matter to physics. So, we don't have the luxury of ignoring those left-handed isometries.

Comment: Thank you for your good and helpful answer.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I understand the motivation behind it, but attempting to characterize vectors by being polar or axial leads to inconsistecies, after all the cross product is $\mathbb{R}^3$ valued, thus if this characterization was consistent, then we'd be able to partition $\mathbb{R}^3$ into polar and axial vectors, with axial vectors being possible results of cross products. But any $\mathbb{R}^3$ vector is a result of a cross product, since if we take your favourite vector $x$ and extend it into a basis, then Gram-Schmidt ortogonalize said basis and rescale the results,

Comment: @JamesS.Cook then $x$ will be the cross product of the rescaling of the last two results of the G-S process. Thus either polar vectors don't exist, or all vectors are both axial and polar.

Comment: @Uldreth yes, but, I think the usage has more to do with how various vectors are defined and how the equations of physics change as we transform coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

You'd best think of the cross product by first defining the following:

Let $\varepsilon:\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a (0,3)-type tensor that is totally antisymmetric. Such tensors form a one-dimensional subspace within the space of (0,3)-type tensors, therefore any such tensor (except the zero tensor) differ only by a scalar factor.

As such, the $\varepsilon$ tensor is uniquely determined by its value on a full set of basis vectors.

Let $E=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let us define this basis to be positively oriented. Then let us define $\varepsilon$ to be $$ \varepsilon(e_1,e_2,e_3)=1. $$ We can think of the list $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ to represent a positively oriented unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$, thus $\varepsilon$ maps oriented volumes to lists of vectors, since we want the volume of a positively oriented unit cube to be 1, and we know that oriented volumes of paralelepipeds are antisymmetric and multilinear in their edges.

If you let $\varepsilon$ act on the basis vectors in any permutation, rather than the positive permutation only, you get $$ \varepsilon(e_i,e_j,e_k)=\epsilon_{ijk} $$ obviously.

Now, letting $x,y$ and $z$ be arbitrary vectors, $\varepsilon(x,y,z)$ is linear in $z$, thus the map $z\mapsto\varepsilon(x,y,z)$ is a linear functional that depends on $x$ and $y$, and by the Riesz representation theorem there exists a unique $x\times y\in\mathbb{R}^3$ vector for which $$ \langle x\times y,z\rangle=\varepsilon(x,y,z).$$

Now, in components, the linear functional mentioned above is $\epsilon_{ijk}x^jy^k$, and the vector, which *is* the cross product is $g^{ij}\epsilon_{jkl}x^ky^l$.

However in $\mathbb{R}^3$, using the standard cartesian coordinates, $g^{ij}=\delta^{ij}$, thus the two are numerically equivalent.

Comment: I wish the standard calculus texts used $\epsilon_{ijk}$ to define the cross-product. It's so clean. It's funny, you also have to raise and lower indices. I'm pretty sure the Riesz rep. step is Hodge duality in your notation.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. I like your approach with the usage of Riesz Theorem.

Comment: @James S. Cook Aye, I just didn't want to invoke hodge duality or exterior algebra altogether, but yes, it is usually baked into it, hence why hodge duality exists only on inner product spaces/riemannian manifolds.